# How to get the username of the current logged in user in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I tried checking out [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo) sample, where we can get all users and their info,
But when I execute  `IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();`
I don't get any values.

And moreover I need to get the current logged in user and not all users,
PS : I have requested the required capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most devices, `FindAllAsync` method returns the user that is currently logged-in and using the app; it doesn't return all the accounts on the machine. Xbox supports two or more people playing the same game at once, so it can return more than one user at a time.

This works fine for me; all you need is the `userAccountInformation` capability:

```
var res = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
foreach (var r in res)
{
  var props = await r.GetPropertiesAsync(new string[] { KnownUserProperties.DisplayName });
  foreach (var p in props)
  {
    Debug.Write(p.Key + ": " + p.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter this works just fine. And I'm using this only on PC so I don't think there would be a problem with multiple users.